# Passing object as parameter in Twig path

Tags: symfony

When I want to pass parameter via Twig path I write:

```
<a href="{{ path('blog_post', { id: post.id }) }}">
```

Is it possible to pass full object e.g. Post via Twig path?

Thank for help

Comment: This will be a URL parameter, so the only option I see is to serialize an object and then base64 encode it. Bad idea. This object will be a part of a URL, and may end up cached, logged, etc...

Comment: Thanks for your opinion.

Comment: Another thing I should add - in case of a GET request, the length of the URL is limited to 2,083 characters. If your object ends up to be longer in encoded form, it will either be truncated or result in a server error.

Comment: May I ask why do you need to pass the full object as a parameter? Is it just that you need a lot of parameters? Or is it that your receiving route needs the object? Also, in the above code, I think you need to enclose id in quotes like so: `<a href="{{ path('blog_post', { 'id': post.id }) }}">`

Comment: @AlvinBunk As far as I know, you are not constraint to write the parameter in quotes.

Comment: I need to pass object to another controller. I know I can pass only id, then in controller use doctrine  findOneByid ($id) to grab . I' m only wondering. Thx again for yours replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, and in my opinion it makes no sense .

How would you want the object to be represented in the **url** ? `'blog/post/{blog.id:1,blog.author:Foo,blog.title:bar}'` ? What if the object change between the time the server display the page (and generate the link)and the time the user clicks on it

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty possible to pass a single numeric `id` to a controller and get the object instance of that id.

Just specify the type of object of the parameter, like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/blog/show/{blog_post}", name="blog-show")
 */
public function showAction(BlogPost $blog_post)
{
    if ($blog_post) {
        var_dump($blog_post)
    }
}
```